# How to convert shapefiles to rasters?

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff

I have my environmental variables such as elevation, soil, vegetation and others as shape-files.

I want to use a raster command to upload them as tiff files for running a boosted regression tree in ecological niche modelling.

How do i convert my shape files to tiff format?